# 403 error when posting to django view from react native

Tags: django, react-native, fetch

I am having a hard time getting data to and from django/react. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

Here is the django view I would like to access

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse

@csrf_exempt 
def getData( requests ):
    return JsonResponse( {"data": "hello world" } )
```

My react native code looks like this:

```
    const fetchSearchItems = ( query ) => {
        console.log( query )
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({ query: query })
        }).then( (data) => {
            console.log( data ) 
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
             // ADD THIS THROW error
              throw error;
        });
    }
```

My django settings.py (updated)

```
ALLOWED_HOST = [ mydomain.com ]
```

My info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>mydomain</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

And finally the error message:

```
{ type: 'default',
  status: 403,
  ok: false,
  statusText: undefined,
  headers: 
   { map: 
      { vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
        date: 'Thu, 10 Sep 2020 18:05:20 GMT',
        'content-type': 'text/html',
        'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
        server: 'PythonAnywhere',
        'referrer-policy': 'same-origin',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        'transfer-encoding': 'Identity',
        'content-encoding': 'gzip' } },
  url: 'xxxxxx',
  bodyUsed: false,
  _bodyInit: 
   { _data: 
      { size: 2864,
        offset: 0,
        blobId: 'EA6FE4A5-BE26-4D8A-98D2-8EA76C248D52',
        type: 'text/html',
        name: 'xxxx',
        __collector: {} } },
  _bodyBlob: 
   { _data: 
      { size: 2864,
        offset: 0,
        blobId: 'EA6FE4A5-BE26-4D8A-98D2-8EA76C248D52',
        type: 'text/html',
        name: 'xxxx',
        __collector: {} } } }
```

I would really appreciate some advice. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding your domain name to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list?

Comment: What errors do you see in your web app logs on PythonAnywhere?

Comment: It was fixed. I would post an answer but I have no idea.